# How can I calculate a field in MS Access 2019 that is the sum of fields in a related table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a worksheet table that has multiple talents linked to it via the Worksheet ID in each of the talent tables.  I want to calculate a field in the worksheet table that is the sum of fields in the talent tables, something like CrewSum: IIF ([CrewTalent]![WorkSheetID] = [Worksheet]![WorkSheetID]) then sum values of [CrewTalent]![InvoiceProductionRate] and place the total in [Worksheet]![CrewSum].

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using  Dsum function.

Read about it.

Comment: Like this?  DSUM( "[InvoiceProductionRate]",  "CrewTalent" ,  "[WorkSheetID] = [Worksheet]![WorkSheetID]" ) but I get the error "The expression ... cannot be used in a calculated column.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DSUM is not supported in an MS Access calculated column.  If it were, its use would be perfect for my purpose.  How else can I do the equivalent?